# text input alignment wrong on mobile devices (possibly only iOS, haven't tried Android)

Tags: html, css, ios

I got 2 forms at my webpage and they are wrongly aligned on iOS devices (iPhone, iPad Safari). On computers it displays correctly (Windows and actually even Mac with Safari) but on mobile devices for some reason the inputs are not centered. Interesting thing is that it's not the whole form but just the input element.
1st picture is how it looks in developer tools in Chrome for example and 2nd picture is how it looks on iphone.

HTML

```
<form class="newsletter-form">
    <div class="newsletter-form-container">
      <input id="newsletter" type="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" />
      <button id="newsletter-send" type="button"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></button>
    </div>
    <p id="newsletter-sub-status"></p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.newsletter-form-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.newsletter-form {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.newsletter-form input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 76px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

there is one more form and that one is positioned static and the inputs are display: block and also displays wrongly. Is this just some iOS thing that I can fix with -webkit something? Couldn't find the answer on google, so I'm trying here.

PS: sorry for different picture sizes, one was taken as phone screenshot and other one is snip from PC.

[image: dev tools phone]

[image: actual phone]

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that, iOS just adds padding to the input element by default and since the default setting for the input is `box-sizing: content-box;` all you have to do is:
a) set padding to the input element to 0 `padding: 0;`
or
b) set `box-sizing: border-box;` and then the padding goes inside the element basically.

final CSS for the element then looks like this:

```
.newsletter-form input {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 76px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```